# Appium desktop issue on Ubuntu

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I've been trying to solve this issue for two weeks and cannot seem to find a solution, it only happens on Appium desktop with `automationName` set to `UiAutomator`.

I changed ownership of the `/tmp` folder from `Root` to `user` and set permissions to `777` but still facing the issue: I cannot change the file's permission since it's a temp folder and its name keeps changing every time I run a new appium session.

This is the error message:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The application at '/tmp/.mount_app.Ap8xEj5P/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' is not writeable. Please grant write permissions to this file or to its parent folder '/tmp/.mount_app.Ap8xEj5P/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks' for the Appium process, so it could sign the application

Comment: Hello @EzCrash welcome to stack overflow seems that someone send you the request of approval of edit please approve if you found it needed

Comment: which appium desktop version are you using?

Comment: @SubanDhyako I'm using 1.12.0 for Linux

Answer (score 0):

You could try to grant permission on `/users/username/node_modules`, `/usr/local` or `/usr/bin`. I ran in the same problem while trying to use UIAutomator2 on macOS and granting permissions gradually. Also, if you have the latest version of Appium, you need to switch to UIAutomator2, starting v12.1 UIAutomator is no longer supported.
Another hint: don't mix UIAutomator with UIAutomator2, check that you are trying to launch with correct capabilities

Comment: I'm using UiAutomator2, I just did what you said but still facing this issue, what else did you do to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

This bug plagued me for weeks before resolving it. The issue ended up being my Java version. I did NOT have to modify signing or read / write privileges on the file in question.

`JAVA_HOME` and `Path` environment variables were both pointing to Java 12. I needed to install `jdk_1.8.0` for Java 8, and update `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` to point to Java 8. More info and possible solutions can be found on my GitHub issue that I opened with Appium devs:

https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/1080